# Is it possible to operate BC548 npn transistor in Active region using single 9Vdc battery?

Tags: transistors

As you can see in the below figure no1, I have used two 9V dc batteries. Here BC548 transistor works in the active region and LED glows.

Whereas in figure 2 , connection is made using single 9 V dc battery but circuit is not working and LED doesn't glow.

What  wrong is happening . Is it possible to operate BC548 npn transistor in Active region using single 9Vdc battery? [image]

Comment: You are shorting the battery in your second circuit.

Comment: Search biasing techniques for BJT

Comment: Yes it's possible.

Comment: @Trevor_G he is shorting the battery dude.

Comment: @Andyaka ya I missed it before I commented, then noticed, then deleted the comment... brain fart. Bad schematics will do that....

Answer (score 2):

This is what you have in the second image, drawn more appropriately, and without the short.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdtTG4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Because the base of the transistor is tied to the 9V rail, the emitter can never be less than a diode drop, the base emitter junction, below 9V. As such the collector can never be less than that. That only leaves under 0.6V across the LED and it's resistor.

You need to wire it like this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fh8Rop.png)</sup>

Comment: OP desired active-region biasing. Perhaps increase R1 to 100k, and wire it from base-to-collector?